# Temperature distribution with advection problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, temperature

A very long pipe enters an oven at $x_1$, with oven temperature set to $T_{\infty}$. Fluid flows through the pipe at mass flow $\dot{m}$ (flow speed is $v$), initially at temperature $T_0$. Flowspeed is so high that turbulent plug flow reigns.

At $t=0$ the oven is switched on to its set temperature. Of course once the fluid flow enters the hot zone the fluid will start to heat up.

I'm looking to find the temperature distribution in time and space, $T(t,x)$ for $x\geq x_1$.

[image: Pipe in oven]

For the purpose of illustration I'll only consider convective heat in the heat balance (radiative and conductive terms can easily be added).

So we consider a mass element $\mathrm{d}m$ (from $x$ to $x+\mathrm{d}x)$ and state its heat balance:

$$c\mathrm{d}m\frac{\mathrm{d}T(x)}{\mathrm{d}t}=c\dot{m}\mathrm{d}T(x)=hP\mathrm{d}x[T_{\infty}-T(x)]$$

with $c$ the specific heat capacity of the fluid, $P$ the circumference of the pipe and $h$ the heat transfer coefficient.

This ODE integrates easily by separation of variables and yields the function $T(x)$:

$$\frac{T(x)-T_{\infty}}{T_0-T_{\infty}}=e^{-\frac{hP}{\dot{m}c}x}$$

and not as the original goal stated, $T(t,x)$.

That's not a great surprise, as I'm not taking into account that the element $\mathrm{d}x$ moves along the $x$-axis in $\mathrm{d}t$, acc. $v\mathrm{d}t$.

I'm wondering wether this is a case of **advection**, and if so, how to apply the advection operator (here in one dimension):

$$v\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$$

I've found precious little *simple* examples of practical application of this operator.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the initial temperature of the fluid in the region x > 0?

Comment: @ChesterMiller: the initial temperature for $x>0$ is $T_0$

Answer (score 1):

The differential equation should be $$\frac{1}{v}\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}=\frac{hP}{\dot{m}c}(T_{\infty}-T)$$This can be solved using the method of characteristics.  The solution is basically $$\frac{(T-T_{\infty})}{(T_0-T_{\infty})}=e^{-\frac{hP}{\dot{m}c}x}\tag{for 0 < x < vt}$$ and
$$\frac{(T-T_{\infty})}{(T_0-T_{\infty})}=e^{-\frac{hP}{\dot{m}c}vt}\tag{for x > vt}$$

Comment: can you elaborate a little on *how* you arrived at this PDE? Or provide a reference to it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: IMO, if there is a fraction in an exponential, you should write it as `\exp` instead to make it actually readable.

Comment: @KyleKanos: as $\exp{\frac{a}{b}}$? I don't like that at all.

Comment: @Gert I'd rather parens there too: $\exp\left(\frac ab\right)$. An alternative would be to just forgo the \frac and use $e^{a/b}$